# android:configChanges seems to be ignored

Tags: android, tabactivity

I try to prevent that onCreate() is called when rotating the device. To reach this goal I followed the documentation and added

```
<activity android:name=".TabActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to the manifest. After that I inserted this to the Activity's source code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

But it seems like Android ignores this method. A breakpoint which I set here is never reached.

What's my fault here? Is this a problem when using tabs?

Regards!

Comment: Your code looks OK. Did you try to set a breakpoint in your `onCreate()` to determine whether it is executed again (it should not as you said) when you switch your device's orientation?

Comment: Just see the post right below. Felix gave a good explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: +1 that's the correct solution. If it doesn't work, try adding `keyboard` as well.

Comment: @J H because the emulator (and some devices) has a physical (emulated) keyboard. Thus, when you rotate it, it actually sends both `keyboardHidden` and `orientation` configuration changes, because it basically emulates popping the physical keyboard out.